# composer install command not working while installing cattr

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, dock

I am trying to isntall cattr opensource script on my ubuntu server.
While i am trying to  run the command `composer install`
I  am getting the following error. I already installed the  PHP modules and followed other system requirements.

```
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 104

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 104
Deprecation Notice: Optional parameter $schema declared before required parameter $path is implicitly treated as a required parameter in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:62
Deprecation Notice: Optional parameter $schema declared before required parameter $path is implicitly treated as a required parameter in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:108
Deprecation Notice: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema/Constraints/Constraint.php:48
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\Repository\\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:206
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\Repository\\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:206
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\Repository\\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:206
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Process::getIterator($flags = 0) should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:606
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\Repository\\ArrayRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:206
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\Repository\\CompositeRepository::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php:139
Loading composer repositories with package information
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Pool::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:166
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php:114
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSet::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php:99
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:155
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:165
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:160
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:170
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:150
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\Decisions::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Decisions.php:145
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSetIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:36
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSetIterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:46
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSetIterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:41
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSetIterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:89
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Composer\\DependencyResolver\\RuleSetIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #\[\\ReturnTypeWillChange\] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetIterator.php:70
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
\- Installation request for jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.5 -\> satisfiable by jean85/pretty-package-versions\[2.0.5\].
\- jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.5 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -\> no matching package found.
Problem 2
\- Installation request for joshbrw/laravel-module-installer v2.0.1 -\> satisfiable by joshbrw/laravel-module-installer\[v2.0.1\].
\- joshbrw/laravel-module-installer v2.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^2.0 -\> no matching package found.
Problem 3
\- jean85/pretty-package-versions 2.0.5 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.0.0 -\> no matching package found.
\- sentry/sentry 3.12.0 requires jean85/pretty-package-versions ^1.5|^2.0.4 -\> satisfiable by jean85/pretty-package-versions\[2.0.5\].
\- Installation request for sentry/sentry 3.12.0 -\> satisfiable by sentry/sentry\[3.12.0\].

Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
  see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
- It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
```

Documentation : https://docs.cattr.app/#/en/advanced/?id=requirements
Composer Json File : https://git.amazingcat.net/cattr/core/cattr-backend/-/blob/main/composer.json